# webcam can't open when run Android application

Tags: android, video

when I run my android camera application in the computer, web camera is not working.

here the code. Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.examples"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
</manifest>
```

main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >
   <FrameLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <SurfaceView
 android:id="@+id/surfaceView1"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 /> 

 </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:layout_marginTop="300px"
 android:paddingLeft="5px"
 android:paddingTop="5px"
 android:paddingRight="5px">    

 <ImageButton
     android:layout_width="50px"
     android:textColor="#ffffff"
     android:layout_height="50px"
     android:id="@+id/cameraClick "
      />

   </LinearLayout> 

   </RelativeLayout>
```

java file

```
 package com.examples;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.hardware.Camera;
 import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
 import android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
 import android.view.SurfaceView;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.ImageButton;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

      private Camera camera;
  private ImageButton cameraClick;
  private SurfaceHolder mHolder; 

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);

   SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
   mHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
   mHolder.addCallback(this);
   mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);  

   cameraClick = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cameraClick);
   cameraClick.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)
              {
 camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback,jpegCallback);
    }
   });  

   }

  // Handles when shutter open
  ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback()
  {
   public void onShutter()
   {   

   }
  };

  /** Handles data for raw picture */
  PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback()
  {
   public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
   {   

   }
  }; 

  /** Handles data for jpeg picture */
  PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback()
 {
   public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
 {
    // we do something using return byte[] of taken image.
   }
  };

  @Override
  public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,int format,int width,int height)
 {

   // Set camera preview size,orientation,rotation using parameters 

 Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
     camera.startPreview();       

  }

  @Override
  public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
 {
   camera = Camera.open();
     try {
     camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    }
 catch (IOException e)
 {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

  @Override
  public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
 {
   camera.stopPreview();
     camera.release();
    camera = null; 

  }

 }
```

when I run this code, web camera can't start. kindly help me to resolve this problem. thanks

Comment: Then what is happening actually? Logcat or any issue you faced?

Comment: when I run this application using Eclipse, web camera has been started and closed suddenly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry about this question. Computer web camera haven't integrated with the Android Emulator. When I do this code, I am just new to the Android. so I didn't know about this simple thing.